# FAB in xamarin forms NOT Working

Tags: xamarin.forms, floating-action-button

I keep getting this error

`Method 'Android.Support.Design.Widget.FloatingActionButton.SetRippleColor' not found.` in my xamarin forms project.

Added the latest versio/2.1.1/2.1.0 , tried with all but i keep getting the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/keannan5390/Xamarin.Plugin.FAB/issues/20

Comment: Any other simpler method ?? didn't quite understand what exactly i need to do ?

Comment: it's an open bug that has not been resolved yet

Comment: Looks like workaround they say: "You can't use SetRippleColor at all. You have to use the RippleColor property, even in the try/catch. Perhaps it's trying to resolve the method/property at method start, not actual call."